# How to point to a jsp which is present inside another project which is bundled as jar and added in the first project?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

The below is my tiles definition present in an xml file. 
The main.jsp is present in another project. This project is bundled as jar by a dependency added in pom.xml of the first project.

```
<definition name="base.definition" **template="/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp"**>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Can someone tell me how to give template path to main.jsp?

Comment: You don't, in any trivial way. JSPs don't really work like that, one reason why other templating technologies are used when sharing templates is a requirement.

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: It's hard to be clearer than "you don't", but I'll try. JSPs cannot have arbitrary paths/locations. They must be in the web app they're being used in, e.g., not from other apps/jars/etc. You can hack JSP engines to work differently, but personally I wouldn't bother. Other templating technologies allow the use of classpath resources as templates. But those other templating technologies aren't JSP.

Comment: Its our requirement. Can you suggest workaround for this?

Comment: Change your requirement. Barring that, create a build step that extracts and repackages the file(s) from the other project.

Comment: "Its our requirement." Its impossible.